# GitHub Reusable Workflow treated as Composite Workflow

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

In a repo I have `.github/workflows/pkg.yml`:

```yaml
---
name: pkg
run-name: ${{ github.actor }} is building package_name
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]
    paths: [pkg/**]
  push:
    paths: [pkg/**]
  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  main:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: ./.github/workflows/reusable/build_python_package.yml
        with:
          package_name: ${{ github.GITHUB_WORKFLOW }}
```

which calls what I intend to be a **Reusable** Workflow in the same repo, `.github/workflows/reusable/build_python_package.yml`:

```yaml
---
name: Build Python Package
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      package_name:
        required: true
        type: string
jobs:
  main:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - name: Install Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
      - name: Install Poetry
        uses: Gr1N/setup-poetry@v8
      - name: Build Python wheels
        run: poetry build
        working-directory: ${{ inputs.package_name }}
```

But when `pkg` runs, I get an error:

```
Error: Can't find 'action.yml', 'action.yaml' or 'Dockerfile' under '/home/runner/work/repo-name/repo-name/.github/workflows/reusable/build_python_package.yml'. Did you forget to run actions/checkout before running your local action?
```

So it seems GitHub Actions is treating `Build Python Package` as a **Composite** Workflow, instead of a **Reusable** Workflow as I intended. I'm not sure why. According to [this](https://dev.to/n3wt0n/composite-actions-vs-reusable-workflows-what-is-the-difference-github-actions-11kd), Composite Workflows don't have a `jobs` block, just a `runs` block.

`Build Python Package` only has a `jobs` block, so it *should* be treated as a *Reusable* Workflow, right?

I want to keep these workflows in the same repo. I want a Reusable Workflow, not a Composite Workflow.

Comment: See [Calling a reusable workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#calling-a-reusable-workflow). The path of the reusable workflow should be **`./.github/workflows/{filename}` for reusable workflows in the same repository**.

Comment: Remove nested `reusable` directory and it should work.

Comment: @Azeem: This doesn't fix it. Instead I get the same error but the new path: `Error: Can't find 'action.yml', 'action.yaml' or 'Dockerfile' under '/home/runner/work/repo-name/repo-name/.github/workflows/build_python_package.yml'. Did you forget to run actions/checkout before running your local action?`

Comment: Please verify the file path with `ls -l /path/to/workflow` in your main workflow.

Comment: Done. It's there. I add a step to `pkg.yml`, `run: ls -l .github/workflows/build_python_package.yml`, and it shows the same location on the runner: `-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker 736 Jun 20 16:52 .github/workflows/build_python_package.yml`

Comment: Are you still using it under a step or directly under job as mentioned in the above link? That must be the issue. Reusable workflows are not callable under a step. You need to call that under job. Please revisit [Calling a reusable workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#calling-a-reusable-workflow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Azeem's comments, here's the solution:

1. Move `.github/workflows/reusable/build_python_package.yml` -> `.github/workflows/build_python_package.yml`
2. Call `.github/workflows/build_python_package.yml` in a job, not a step.

Here are my final files:

```
|-- repo-name/
|---- .github/workflows/
|-------- pkg.yml
|-------- build_python_package.yml
```

`.github/workflows/pkg.yml`:

```yaml
---
name: pkg
run-name: ${{ github.actor }} is building package_name
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]
    paths: [pkg/**]
  push:
    paths: [pkg/**]
  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  # No need to checkout the repo here.
  # All reusable workflows must be in .github/workflows/ only!
  main:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/build_python_package.yml
    with:
      package_name: ${{ github.GITHUB_WORKFLOW }}
```

`.github/workflows/build_python_package.yml`:

```yaml
---
name: Build Python Package
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      package_name:
        required: true
        type: string
jobs:
  main:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      # Checkout the repo _here_. A reusable workflow can't access any
      # files checked out in the parent workflow!
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
      - name: Install Poetry
        uses: Gr1N/setup-poetry@v8
      - name: Build Python wheels
        run: poetry build
        working-directory: ${{ inputs.package_name }}
```